# Google OAuth2 Error 400 when exchanging for an Access Token

Tags: api, oauth

I am receiving  a "400 Bad Request" error when using the following VBA code to exchange a valid Authorization token for an access token in the Google API.  Can anyone shed light as to why, I have been struggling with this one for over a week.

```
Dim http As MSXML2.XMLHTTP
Dim sUrl As String
Dim sUrlHeader As String
Dim svarbody As String

Set http = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP

sUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token? HTTP/1.1"

http.Open "POST", sUrl


http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

svarbody = "code=4%2FXAjmXiUlBXUAUGCnMvNKsxdyuJEJ.8kfzzrqo3wwTuJJVnL49Cc9gML_lbgI&" & _
"client_id=50487549202#-q27v28nvhmjhc0uobq35tjn09lhrh47r.apps.googleusercontent.com&" &         _
"redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&" & _
"scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fcalendar%2Ffeeds&" & _
"client_secret=<secret delete for this post>&" & _
"grant_type=authorization_code"

http.send svarbody

Me.Text3 = http.status & vbCrLf & http.statusText & vbCrLf & http.responseText
```

Comment: You should really look for the response body and see what it says.  This often gives an indication as to what's causing the 400 error.

Answer (score 0):

this is a very very common problem. You may try to solve it doing many approaches and tests... but...

The really one you should try in the first place is:

UPDATE YOUR SERVER/COMPUTER WINDOWS CLOCK, USE time.nist.gov (or brothers). Double-click in your Windows Hour-Date (on the bottom of your screen and change Internet Time in this way)

SntsDev

Answer (score 0):

In my experience using Oauth 2.0 in VBA this error happens when you use the code more than once for requesting a token. The usage sequence I use based on the documentation and experience is:
access GET https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth **once** for geting the code
access POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token **once** for geting the token
after that use the token as long as it is valid

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you need set up billing info in your google account.